# Tilt map in Mapkit programmatically using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'd like to tilt the map at startup. (Same as the user does when scrolling up or down with 2 fingers)

Is this possible using Swift?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MKMapView Class Reference : http://goo.gl/djHXPn

Look at the `camera` property :

> A camera object defines a point above the map’s surface from which to view the map. Applying a camera to a map has the effect of giving the map a 3D-like appearance. You can use a camera to rotate the map so that it is oriented to match the user’s heading or to apply a pitch angle to tilt the plane of the map.
>
> Assigning a new camera to this property updates the map immediately and without animating the change. If you want to animate changes in camera position, use the setCamera:animated: method instead.
>
> You must not set this property to nil. To restore the map to a flat appearance, apply a camera with a pitch angle of 0, which yields a camera looking straight down onto the map surface.

Try to create and set a camera (animated or not).

**Edit :**

I tried myself. Here is an example of how to use it :

```
let userCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 58.592725, longitude: 16.185962)
let eyeCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 58.571647, longitude: 16.234660)
let mapCamera = MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenterCoordinate: userCoordinate, fromEyeCoordinate: eyeCoordinate, eyeAltitude: 400.0)

let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.setCoordinate(userCoordinate)

mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

mapView.setCamera(mapCamera, animated: true)
```

You'll have to find your right `eyeCoordinate` depending on your location and tilt effect you want to have.

Comment: I've added an example :)

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 4**

This is an easier way: you can set distance, pitch and heading:

```
let mapCamera = MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenter: userCoordinate, fromDistance: 10000, pitch: 65, heading: 0)
map.setCamera(mapCamera, animated: true)
```