# MapKit camera on xcode using swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, mkmapview, mapkit

I got the following code from [Tilt map in Mapkit programmatically using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28886169/tilt-map-in-mapkit-programmatically-using-swift) but I'm not sure what to do with it. I want my map to be in like a 45 degree angle, kind of like when you use the maps app and you drag up using 2 fingers, I want my camera to always be that way.

```
let userCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 58.592725, longitude: 16.185962)
let eyeCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 58.571647, longitude: 16.234660)
let mapCamera = MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenterCoordinate: userCoordinate, fromEyeCoordinate: eyeCoordinate, eyeAltitude: 400.0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we need to import MapKit.

`import MapKit`

Then in the class we need to incorporate the MKMapViewDelegate protocol and make the MapView object, and set the attributes to make what you desire.

```
class ExampleClassController: MKMapViewDelegate {
   @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           let userCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 58.592725, longitude: 16.185962)
           let eyeCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 58.571647, longitude: 16.234660)
           let mapCamera = MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenterCoordinate: userCoordinate, fromEyeCoordinate: eyeCoordinate, eyeAltitude: 400.0)
           let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
           annotation.setCoordinate(userCoordinate)

           //Setup our Map View
           mapView.delegate = self
           mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Standard
           mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
           mapView.setCamera(mapCamera, animated: true)

           ...

       }

    ...
 }
```

Hope that helps!