# is there a way of showing MKMapView from an angle (not directly from the top) on a specific zoom level?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit, mkmapviewdelegate

In `swift` I'm using `MapKit`.

I set up the outlet `@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!`, used the `MKMapViewDelegate`, and then I'm adding some annotations.

I was wondering if there's a possibility to show my map tilted and disable changing it until user zooms out the map. So basically when he zooms in - from the specific zoom level up to the closest zoom - he would only see this:

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

and changing this option by scrolling with two fingers should be locked.
When user zooms out to some specific zoom level (e.g. country-wise), then it could switch to non-3d map. Is that achievable?

Answer (score 4):

### Later edit:

The `MKMapView` has a property called `camera`(details [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapview/1452277-camera)) which is an instance of `MKMapCamera`. You can use that property to set your desired angle. Be aware that the camera can be pitched only at certain zoom levels. Based on Apple's documentation you can check if the camera can be pitched at any given moment by checking the `isPitchEnabled` property on the map view object.

### Original answer

Try using an instance of `MKMapCamera`. From the documentation that should allow you to set the desired perspective angle and zoom level by setting it's `pitch`, `heading`and `altitude` properties.

You can read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapcamera).

Comment: Hm so I found quite similar problem here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28886295/3766930 but I have some doubts - first, I don't always have the user's location, so I don't know how to initiate the camera without it... Also, is there a way of locking the pitch on a certain level? I don't see any option for it in the docs :|

Comment: You might not have the user's location, but you have the map location right? That's what you'd use. As for locking values, you should be able to do that that by subclassing MKMapCamera

Comment: @BenKane culd you give me some example of how could that be made? I went through MKMapCamera methods and I didn't see any possibilities to do so :|

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
            camera.pitch = 85.0
            camera.altitude = 223.0
            camera.heading = 31.2

            self.mapView.isPitchEnabled = true;
            self.mapView.showsBuildings = true;
```